# How come I cant update my php from 5.4.38 to a newer version on my mac?

Tags: php, macos, cakephp, terminal, mamp

I am trying to install Cakephp in my computer, so I go to my htdocs on my MAMP server and
 when I am trying to execute:

```
Fernandos-iMac:CakephpYoutube fernando$ php composer.phar create-project --prefer-dist cakephp/app bookmarker
```

It gives me an error saying

```
- cakephp/cakephp 3.2.1 requires php >=5.5.9 -> your PHP version (5.4.38) does not satisfy that requirement.
```

So I tried php -v and it does say I am running  PHP version (5.4.38) but on my MAMP PHPinfo it says I am using PHP Version 5.5.9. So I am very confused on how to update my PHP so I can work on CakePHP through my MAMP.

any suggestions?

Comment: please note that MAMP come with two PHP version (one of this is 559!) Go to MAMP prefs and simply change PHP version

Comment: I tried that but it still says I am using an older version on Terminal 
 `code 


Fernandos-iMac:CakephpYoutube fernando$ php -v
PHP 5.4.38 (cli) (built: Mar 19 2015 14:49:15) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies `

Comment: but do you have restarted before setting prefs?

Comment: Yhea I closed and reopen MAMP and tried php -v but still says  PHP 5.4.38 . :/ ... did you mean restarting the whole computer perhaps?

Comment: I don't sure. I don't know MAMP very well. I have found that info in the net. Maybe a restart of whole computer can work, because I imagine that apache is active at boot also if MAMP is closed... but it's only an idea, I'm not an expert, I'm sorry

Comment: Nah, it didnt work, I am going to try to upgrade my Mac to El Capitan, maybe thats the problem.

Comment: mmhhh... Are you sure? Try to search google something like 'MAMP php 5.5.9' to see if anyone have a similar issue.